# codeigniter flatten array of query result

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm using a query in Codeigniter to return the ids of all the rows that belong to a user.

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('user_id', 99);
$query = $this->db->get('my_table');
return $query->result_array();
```

This returns

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 8 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 7 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 6 ) )
```

Is it possible to return a flat array like

```
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 )
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CodeIgniter documentation (most particularly, [query results](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)) doesn't list anything that will produce a flat array result (like the [`PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`](https://php.net/PDO.constants#pdo.constants.fetch-column) mode provided for [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](https://php.net/PDOStatement.fetchAll)). As such, array results will need to be flattened in your code, such as with a `foreach` loop:

```
$flat = array();
foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $flat[] = $row['id'];
}
```

or with the special purpose [`array_column`](https://php.net/array_column):

```
array_column($query->result_array(), 'id');
```

or with the general purpose [`array_reduce`](https://php.net/array_reduce):

```
array_reduce(
    $results, 
    fn ($accum, $row) => array_merge($accum, [$row['id']]),
    []);
```

If you're to lazy to add few lines each time you select one column, you would need to tweak CodeIgniter. Like adding some option or returning flattened array when single column is selected. I would suggest adding an option

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that codeignter had a built in function.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store the result of the function in a variable rather than calling the function each for loop?

Comment: Unless modifying by reference, `foreach()` "makes a copy" and plays with that.  As a consequence of that behavior, the `result_array()` method is not called iteratively. @user2019515

Answer (score 0):

Following can be another way of dong it. I don't know what is the advantage of it over the accepted answer.

Let's say you are storing output of function in `$result`. Then you can do as following:

```
array_unshift($result, null);
$transposed = call_user_func_array("array_map", $result);
print_r($transposed);
```

It will print

> Array( [0] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 ))

And you can access what you want by $transposed[0]

> Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 )